# Laravel - Define relationship with string like xyz instead of using id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a table that storing information about an event. The event has a location attribute (String). Now I have a table `locations` table that stores location names together with their address.

Now I want to fetch all events from the database together with their location.

Because I get all the events from an external source, I can't use ids to setup a relationship.

So what I need is a relationship that works something like `$this->hasOne('Location')->where('name','LIKE','%location_name%');`

Is something like this possible? If not, what would be the best practice to achieve something like this so I get an output JSON like this:

```
 {
    "name":"Event Abc",
    "date":"2019-10-18 12:00:00",
    "location":"Location X",
    "location_details": {
        "name":"Location X",
        "address":"Street XYZ"
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do a join on a `name` column instead, but I don't think you can use that with a `like` operator. In Laravel, you'd do `$this->hasOne('Location', 'name', 'location');` (might not be quite right, but 2nd and 3rd params are how you specify join columns)

Comment: @TimLewis - `$this->hasOne('Location', 'name', 'location');`, works - but LIKE would be better

Comment: Right, but that's not how `join`s work in SQL. `hasOne()` (and the other relationship methods, `belongsTo()`, etc.) constructs the join logic for linking the two tables, so the column values need to be an exact match. Again, `varchar` columns (strings) can be used in `join`s, but not with wildcard checks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. But you need little modification. So lets try and let me know what happened

```
function location () {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Location')->where('name','LIKE','%location_name%')->get();
    }
```

then call it from your controller

```
    $eventsWithlocation = Event::with('location')->first();
      dd($eventsWithlocation);
```

Comment: `ErrorException: Array to string conversion` ... so it does not work!

Comment: sorry there will be a first() instead of get().i edited my answer can you try this

Comment: That edit would make no difference in your code... `dd()` handles a `Collection` (result of `->get()`) and an `Event` instance (result of `->first()`) just fine

Comment: then why he get this error can you help me because he has the one to one relation. thats why in model i use first(). So, i thought in controller there should be first() as he is got the error for array to string

Comment: There might be different code that causes that error that they didn't bother to show, but in your example, `->get()` and `->first()` doesn't make a difference; `dd($eventsWithlocation);` will work with either.